# Can I add protected void onResume() to Fragment class to launch something when the UI restored in Android?

Tags: android

In AppCompatActivity , I can add the code `protected void onResume()` to launch some function when UI is shown or restored.

Now I created a Tabbed Activity, I add the code `protected void onResume()` to PlaceholderFragmentOld class , and I hope the system do someting when the UI cleanup_delete_fragment_old is shown, but the system crash and return the following error.

```
android.support.v4.app.SuperNotCalledException: Fragment PlaceholderFragmentOld{40e55078 #0 id=0x7f0f0070 android:switcher:2131689584:0} did not call through to super.onResume()
```

**PlaceholderFragmentOld.java**

```
public class PlaceholderFragmentOld extends Fragment {

    private AdView adView;
    private SMSRange mSmsRange;

    private View mView;
    private Context mContext;
    private Spinner spinnerRanger;
    private CheckBox chIsWriteLog;

    public PlaceholderFragmentOld() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cleanup_delete_fragment_old, container, false);

        mView=rootView;
        mContext=rootView.getContext();


        return rootView;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
       DoSometing();
    }
}
```

**CleanupDelete.java**

```
public class CleanupDelete extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cleanup_delete);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }


    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment;
            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    fragment = new PlaceholderFragmentOld();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fragment = new PlaceholderFragmentReduce();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fragment = new PlaceholderFragmentTrim();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    fragment = new PlaceholderFragmentPerson();
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid section number");
            }

            return fragment;
        }



        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.Tab_Old);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.Tab_Reduce);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.Tab_Trim);
                case 3:
                    return getString(R.string.Tab_Person);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add `onResume()` to a `Fragment`.

The error your getting states:

```
SuperNotCalledException: PlaceholderFragmentOld did not call through to super.onResume()
```

You need to call `super.onResume()` as the first line in your `onResume()` method, otherwise the system will complain. Something like this would work

```
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!    I add the following code. When I switch to the PlaceholderFragmentOl Tab from other Tabs, sometimes "I am back"  displayed and sometimes it don't display, why?   @Override
    public void onResume() {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "I am back",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onResume();

    }